# BitmapImage Не удается декодировать изображение

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapimage

Сохраняю изображение в массив байтов, перед этим произвел конвертацию изображения в JPEG.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID  
                // for the Quality parameter category.  
                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

                // Create an EncoderParameters object.  
                // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter  
                // objects. In this case, there is only one  
                // EncoderParameter object in the array.  
                EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

                EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 20L);
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
                image.Save(ms, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                imgData = ms.ToArray();
            }
```

После получаю изображение, но мне выдает Exception

> Не удается декодировать изображение. Возможно, поврежден заголовок
>   изображения c#

Передается только нормально, если я укажу формат ImageFormat.PNG без конвертации. А ImageFormat.Jpeg, не работает никак

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData, 0, imgData.Length))
            {
                ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

                bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmap.EndInit();
                bitmap.Freeze();
            }
```

Comment: А какого типа ваш `image`?

Comment: @VladD,  Image image

Comment: Скорее всего вы не сохраняете заголовок, недавно на SO был похожий вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639825/f-creating-bitmap-from-a-memory-stream-throwing-an-exception/43642799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

И все заработало отлично

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData, 0, imgData.Length))
            {
                ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
                bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.Default;
                bitmap.EndInit();
                bitmap.Freeze();
            }
```